# display pi in its greek version in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, phpmyadmin

I want to store the greek version of letter pi in phpmyadmin, how can I do this. I have a form in which I have a textarea. When user enter some text which include a greek letter,(say, pi in this case) I want its greek symbol to be stored in phpmyadmin database.

For writing pi in textarea I copied the text from internet and paste it in the textarea, but when I submit the form, something else is being stored  in database.

Here are the images:-

[image: copied pi from web]

[image: saved as some junk text]

Comment: Try encoding it in `utf-8` format. while loading data from external sheet. And while creating table give `default charset=utf8;` at the end like:  

`create table if not exists test.user1(id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  role tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
) engine = InnoDB default charset = utf8;`

It's an example,so follow this way while creating table,it'll store data as `utf8` and will display it as `utf8` encoded data. i.e: `pi` in proper way